# Differentiate between types of open graph object pages

Tags: html, facebook-graph-api, facebook

One of our applications uses open graph tags so that when users like or comment on a page, the resulting feed story is rich with content, images etc.

Another part of our application (the web platform side) allows users to connect to a Facebook profile page so they can manage the wall, add apps to their profile page etc.

Trouble is, by calling /me/accounts, you get all open graph objects that user has rights to and not just the proper profile pages.

Is there any way to differentiate between types do the users don't have potentially thousands of pages to sift through when they want to connect to their profile page? For example, in Facebook, if I click "Use Facebook as a Page" in the top right drop down, that list is filtered to be just the profile pages and not every single open graph object I'm considered an admin for. How can we get just that list of pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use FQL for that, the following query should give you relevant info:

```
SELECT page_id, type
  FROM page_admin 
 WHERE uid=me()
   AND type="COMPANY"
```

hope this helps

Comment: Of course this only returns pages of type 'company' and not the other valid page types of profile page i.e. if a profile page is set to type 'PRODUCT/SERVICE'